# What does "more to strike up conversation than for any other reason" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> I was quiet. I accept I was a noisy eater and muncher, but I said nothing. No-one did. Hymer watched grumpily as I ate. “If you eat like that, it’ll be fish tomorrow,” he said, “We can’t kill 3 oxen every day for dinner."" It was a tasty meal, and I felt pleasantly full after eating up the ox. **“Phew,” I said, more to strike up conversation than for any other reason, for the hall was not cheerful.** “Did you say you are going fishing tomorrow? I’d like to come. Will you take me? I’ve strong arms for the rowing...”

I think the sentence in bold means that Thor wants to conversation much because the Hall wasn't cheerful, but I don't understand "than for".

What would be the difference if I used "from" instead of "than for"?

“Phew,” I said, more to strike up conversation **than for** any other reason, for the hall was not cheerful.
“Phew,” I said, more to strike up conversation **from** any other reason, for the hall was not cheerful.

Comment: He said it 'to strike up conversation' **more than** 'for any other reason'. (In other words, he didn't have any other reason.)

Comment: I've edited your question to try to make it more clear what you're asking about. If I have misunderstood, please [edit] your question to correct me.

Comment: wants to conversation [buzzer]

Answer (score 0):

Why did Thor respond to  Hymer's words about fish? The most common reason to speak is the wish to say something in particular, but that's not why he spoke. He was distressed by the fact that the hall was not cheerful and
just wanted get a conversation going about anything at all. That was the real reason - more than any other.

I don't understand what your rewording is trying to say.